# Slow disk speed with rsync, but not in benchmark or with other disks

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, 19.10, rsync, ext4

I have some problems with my self builded multimediabox. I have 4HDDs in it to store music, movies and backups from computers from the network.

I got all backups on one buffer disk (Seagate 8TB Ironwolf) and now I want to backup that files to a separated disk (Seagate 8TB Barracuda) from time to time. At first I get a huge speed but after 10min the speed drops dramatically. I tested it with about 80GB of Linux Backups. 
When I put the data to another disk I get about 40-50MB/s with rsync (--stats). On the Barracuda disk I got only 2MB/s but I don't know why. When I take a look on atop and top I have a really huge CPU load when copying to that disk (40-80%), the paging is huge, but the disk as a low activity (0-5%). When copying to other disks I have a small CPU load but much more disk activity (50-80%)

When copying 50GB in small blocks via dd to the disks results in a huge write speed (>100MB/s)

Does anyone have an idea what causes this error?

I also tried other SATA ports and cables, but the error is still there. All disks have a ext4 filesystem.

Thanks!

Comment: Is rsync encryption/decryption taking all the CPU time? There used to be a way to speed up rsync by specifying arcfour cipher, but it has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I am only using it in a local system (disk to disk transfer) so I think no encryption should be used.

The crazy thing is, that I only have this errors with this specific disk, not with disks

Comment: I am not aware that encryption/decryption can be disabled, and your high CPU usage is consistent with encryption/decryption being the bottle neck.